# functional components with redux, search textbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react application and a search functionality. But now I try to implement redux within the application.

So I don't want to have this anymore:

```
 //const [searchfield, stateSearchField] = useState('');
```

But if I load the app I get now this errors:

```
ReferenceError: searchfield is not defined
(anonymous function)
E:/Mijn Documents/UDEMY/REACT/robofriends-master/src/containers/App.js:41
  38 | 
  39 | 
  40 | const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
> 41 |   return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
     | ^  42 | });
  43 | return !robots.length ?
  44 |   <h1>Loading</h1> :
```

index.js:

```
const store = createStore(searchRobots);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <App  />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
 registerServiceWorker();
```

So this is app.js:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    searchField: state.searchfield
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value))
  }
}

function App(props) {
  

  const [robots, robotState] = useState([]);
  //const [searchfield, stateSearchField] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => { robotState(users) });   
  }, []);


  const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
    return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
  });
  return !robots.length ?
    <h1>Loading</h1> :
    (
      <div className='tc'>
        <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={setSearchField} />
        <Scroll>
          <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
        </Scroll>
      </div>
    );

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

reducer.js:

```
import { CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD } from './constants.js';


const initialState = {
    searchField: ''
}

export const searchRobots = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD:
            return Object.assign({}, state, { searchField: action.payload });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

actions.js

```
import {CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD} from './constants'

export const setSearchField = (text)=> ({
                type: CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
                payload: text

});
```

searchbox.js

```
const SearchBox = ({ searchfield, searchChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className='pa2'>
      <input
        className='pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue'
        type='search'
        placeholder='search robots'
        onChange={e =>searchChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

my question: what I have to change so that it will now use redux?

Thank you

I try it like this:

```
  const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
    return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(props.searchField.toLowerCase());
  });
  return !robots.length ?
    <h1>Loading</h1> :
    (
      <div className='tc'>
        <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={props.onSearchChange} />
        <Scroll>
          <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
        </Scroll>
      </div>
    );
```

But then I will get this error:

```
ypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
(anonymous function)
E:/Mijn Documents/UDEMY/REACT/robofriends-master/src/containers/App.js:40
  37 | 
  38 | 
  39 | const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
> 40 |   return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(props.searchField.toLowerCase());
     | ^  41 | });
  42 | return !robots.length ?
  43 |   <h1>Loading</h1> :
```

I also tried this:

```
 console.log(props.store);
```

But then I get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to edit the App in the following way it should works:

```js
function App(props) {

  const [robots, robotState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => { robotState(users) });   
  }, []);

  const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
    return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(props.searchField.toLowerCase());
  });
  return !robots.length ?
    <h1>Loading</h1> :
    (
      <div className='tc'>
        <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={props.onSearchChange} />
        <Scroll>
          <CardList robots={filteredRobots} />
        </Scroll>
      </div>
    );

}
```

You have to use the state props passed from redux to your component inside `props`.

Another problem is that you have a typo inside the `mapStateToprops`, it should be like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    searchField: state.searchField
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans ware. See my edit post.

Comment: I updated the answer, there is a typo in your code: `searchfield` should be `searchField`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Yes, and then in SearchBox.js changing this: onChange={searchChange}